# How to help with Android translations?

Tags: localization

I'm a Android user. I've used both G1 and my current phone Nexus One. The one problem I see in Android is that it lacks a good translation for my native language (Spanish), so the question is: where do I have to go to help with Android platform translations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by trying the [Android Contributors Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-contrib/topics?start=).

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-contrib/browse_thread/thread/42cc4b7de00d3362#) is a thread on reviewing Googles own Catalan translation work, for example.